# How to Split a column into two by comma delimiter, and put a value without comma in second column and not in first?

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I have a column in a df that I want to split into two columns splitting by comma delimiter. If the value in that column does not have a comma I want to put that into the second column instead of first.

| Origin |
| --- |
| New York, USA |
| England |
| Russia |
| London, England |
| California, USA |
| USA |

I want the result to be:

| Location | Country |
| --- | --- |
| New York | USA |
| NaN | England |
| NaN | Russia |
| London | England |
| California | USA |
| NaN | USA |

I used this code
`df['Location'], df['Country'] = df['Origin'].str.split(',', 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `str.extract` here:

```py
df["Location"] = df["Origin"].str.extract(r'(.*),')
df["Country"] = df["Origin"].str.extract(r'(\w+(?: \w+)*)$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way by using `str.extract()` and named groups

```
df['Origin'].str.extract(r'(?P<Location>[A-Za-z ]+(?=,))?(?:, )?(?P<Country>\w+)')
```

Output:

```
     Location  Country
0    New York      USA
1         NaN  England
2         NaN   Russia
3      London  England
4  California      USA
5         NaN      USA
```